# Opening photo gallery with keyboard open causes widget to be squished downwards behind the keyboard by a few pixels

Tags: flutter

I have made a simple text editor with an InkWell at the bottom of the page that has a function to add images. Everything seems to work fine, but there is an issue with the InkWell. When I click on the text editor, the keyboard opens up.

However, when the keyboard is open and I press the InkWell to go to the photo gallery to choose an image, then return (or exit the photo gallery), the InkWell is pushed below the keyboard by a little bit.

In other words, opening up the photo gallery while the keyboard is open causes my InkWell to shift downwards.

I have wrapped my TextField in an Expanded so that my InkWell is always at the bottom of the screen. Everything works fine except that the InkWell shifts downwards upon entering and exiting photo gallery.

A simplified reproducible version of the code is below.

[image: Squished down]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 100),
            const Expanded(
              child: TextField(
                maxLines: 60,
                minLines: 2,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText:
                      'Start a conversation.',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    color: Color(0xffBFBFBF),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            //Pressing InkWell will open image gallery
            InkWell(
              onTap: () async {
                  await _pickImage();
              },
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.lightBlue,
                child: Container(
                  height: 40,
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  child: const Row(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(width: 28),
                      Icon(
                        Icons.photo,
                        size: 20,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "0/3",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
  
  // Function to handle image selection
  Future<void> _pickImage() async {
    final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
    final XFile? pickedImage = await picker.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
    );
  }
}
```